# Increment shared preference key after adding value

Tags: android, key, sharedpreferences

In my app, the user can add a name and an age for multiple people. Most likely it will only be around 2 or 3. I want to store these in shared preferences. I set a counter to keep track of how many people have been stored as well as to manage which key goes with which value. I took the edittext input and put it in a string and then put it into the shared preferences like so, adding on the counter so I know that is the first person and would access the person with "name1".

```
//this is in the class
public int count = 1;

//this is in the main
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("registerData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            myEditor.putString("Name"+count, name);
            myEditor.putString("Age"+count, age);
```

Unless I am mistaken, that should put the string "name" into "Name1".

Then I go and try to access it in another activity with...

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("registerData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("Name"+count,"");
    String age = sharedPreferences.getString("Age"+count,"");
```

Then i would update the counter before the next person would be added to change the key to "Name2" "Age2", and so on.

Whenever I try to set the strings to a textview, they show up blank. Which means its not the same String to access the key. The putString has to get the "Name1", because even when I try to access the getString("Name",""), it's still blank.  Is there something I'm doing wrong or missing. Or there is a better way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: *and so on.* .... in other words you need database not sharedpreferences

Comment: because you have incremented the count and now trying to get the string Name"+count as this will result in name2

Comment: I'm just questioning using database because there will be no more than 3 people added to it. Would it be worth it to do that other than sharedpreferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("registerData",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        myEditor.putString("Name"+count, name);
        myEditor.putString("Age"+count, age);
        myEditor.apply();//returns nothing,don't forgot to commit changes
```

also you can use

```
      myEditor.commit() //returns true if the save works, false otherwise.
```

Comment: Do not use commit on an ui thread. Use apply() instead.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something I'm doing wrong or missing. Or there is a better
>   way of doing this?

If `SharedPreferences` key names are dynamic then you should use  [SharedPreferences.getAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29) which return all keys available in selected preference:

```
Map<String, ?> allKeys = sharedPreferences.getAll();
```

Now iterate through `allKeys` to check key names and get values from `Map.Entry`  related to key like:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allKeys.entrySet()) {
    Log.v("TAG","Key Name :" entry.getKey());
    Log.v("TAG","Key Value :" entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call [apply()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) on the shared preference editor after making changes.

```
...
myEditor.apply();
```

Shared preferences however, are not meant to store content related data. Consider using more appropriate solutions like a database.